# Discord.py: Going through a specific channel's history, picking a random message and sending it's link

Tags: discord.py

The context I'm using this in is for a Clip of the week command, in which the bot will go through an already created channel filled with clips, pick one at random and send the message link of that message.

From reading the docs, I imagine I'd have to use `channel.history` and `jump_url`, but I cannot figure out how to utilise them for my scenario.

I did figure out how to do the weekly cooldown -
`@commands.cooldown(1, 604800, commands.BucketType.user)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were heading in the right direction with `channel.history` and the `message.jump_url`. Here's an example on how you would do that:

```py
import random

@bot.command()
async def randommsg(ctx):
    messages = await ctx.channel.history(limit=None).flatten()
    random_message = random.choice(messages)
    await ctx.send(random_message.jump_url)
```

You can replace the limit with whatever you want, 100 is the default, None gets every message in the channel. (Note: getting every message is incredibly slow in channels with lots of messages. I had around 3k messages in mine and it took over a minute as reference.)

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#discord.TextChannel.history